# Run dbt test on a single model.yml related to the table alias with different schema

Tags: google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I’ve got 2 tables : `my_table_1` and `my_table_2` created from a model `my_table` with a dynamic alias where the alias is set up through the dag.

The differences with the two of them are the alias of course but also a column name.
In other words, the `my_table_1` schema has the common columns whereas the `my_table_2` schema has a column `country` populated along with the common columns shared with `my_table_1`.

Creating the tables with the different schema is straight forward but I’m stuck with the `my_table.yml` and its schema for the testing.

What I’m trying to achieve is to run the `my_table.yml` using `dbt test` that would read the `my_table_1` schema **without** the column `country` but would do it with the `my_table_2` schema **with** the column `country`
I tried to add a if-statement in the yml file but it doesn’t seem to work (see below).

Do you have any idea how I can achieve that please ?

```
my_table.yml 

models:
    - marts:
      name: my_table      
      columns:
{% if alias == "my_table_2" %}
       - name: country
         tests:
           - not_null:
               config:
                 severity: error
{% endif %}
        - name: id
          tests:
           - not_null:
               config:
                 severity: error
        - name: name
          tests:
           - not_null:
               config:
                 severity: error
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional `expression_is_true` from the `dbt_utils` package.

```
my_table.yml 

models:
    - marts:
      name: my_table
      tests:
        - dbt_utils.expression_is_true:
            expression: "{% if config.get('alias') == 'my_table_2' %} COUNTRY IS NOT NULL {% else %} TRUE {% endif %}"
```